# While loop not executing

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, while-loop, greatest-common-divisor

i am new to java and need help please. My while loop isn't working. It doesn't execute anything other than count.

For this question I need to make fraction class that has mutator and accessory methods. Then I have to make the numerator and denominator to lowest form so i am use while loop to find greatest common divisor by using module. Any other critic is also appreciated.

```
public class Fraction {
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;
    public Fraction(){

    }
    public Fraction(int num, int den){
        this.numerator = num;
        this.denominator = den;
    }

    public void setNumerator(int numerator){
        this.numerator = numerator;
    }
    public void setDenominator(int denominator){
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }
    public double divided(){
        double divide = (double)this.numerator/this.denominator;
        return divide;
    }
    public String printFraction(){
        int numerator = greatestCommmonNumetaror();
        return "";
    }
    private int greatestCommmonNumetaror(){
        int count = 1;
        int first;
        int mod;
        while(count != this.numerator){// need help with this
            mod = this.numerator%count;
            if(mod != 0){
                first = count;
                if(first < count){
                    first = count;
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by " It doesn't execute anything other than count."

Comment: Put in some `println`s so you know for sure what is running.

Comment: I'm not sure what your while loop is trying to achieve. You set a bunch of variables but don't seem to use them, then at the end you just return "1". Can you describe in words what the algorithm is trying to do?

Comment: first = count;
                if(first < count){
                    first = count;
                } // if statement will never be true

Comment: Please clarify what you think your loop is doing, and what you think it should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While loop very well executes if you call that.
Just added couple of System.out.println and you can see that it is executing:

```
private int greatestCommmonNumetaror(){
    int count = 1;
    int first;
    int mod;
    System.out.println("Outside while: count is "+count+" and this.numerator is "+this.numerator);
    while(count != this.numerator){// need help with this
        System.out.println("In while: Count is "+count);
        mod = this.numerator%count;
        System.out.println("In while: mod is "+mod);
        if(mod != 0){
            first = count;
            System.out.println("In while and if: first is "+first+" and count is "+count);
            if(first < count){
                first = count;
                System.out.println("In while and if and if: first is "+first+" and count is "+count);
            }
        }
        count++;
    }
    return 1;
}

public String printFraction(){
    int numerator = greatestCommmonNumetaror();
    return "";
}
```

Also added below mentioned code to call printFraction:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Fraction fraction = new Fraction(3,5);
    fraction.printFraction();
}
```

And you can see the output:

```
Outside while: count is 1 and this.numerator is 3
In while: Count is 1
In while: mod is 0
In while: Count is 2
In while: mod is 1
In while and if: first is 2 and count is 2
```

So it does goes to while loop.

*Edit: Although using System.out.println you should be able to see the issue with your algorithm but still if you have any further issue, can you please explain your algorithm with example.

Answer (score -2):

Just use numerator get rid of the this.numerator in the loop

Comment: I wasn't the dvter but your answer does absolutely nothing to fix his problem.

Comment: The only scenario where `this.x` is different from `x` is if you have both a parameter `x` in a function/constructor, and your object also has a variable called `x`. In that case, you use `this.x` to differentiate between the parameter provided and the actual member of the object.

Comment: yes but if statements arent executed, only count is executed in that loop